FAILED systemd-networkd-wait-online.service on Raspberry Pi with OpenMediaVault
I am relatively new to system administration, etc.
As a personal project, I am trying to build a home server using Raspberry Pi 4 and OpenMediaVault 6.
I am following the official guide from OpenMediaVault. Which basically is running the update, then update, then reboot, then run the script to install OMV.
The issue seems to emerge after make any change to the Network in the OMV interface (my last change was set the DNS to 8.8.8.8). I also let OMV do the updates from the Update tab by clicking on it (I don't thing this is relevant, but you never know).
After a reboot, my router does not see my RPi anymore. When I directly connect the RPi to my monitor to see what is happening I see the message:
[FAILED] Failed to start systemd-networkd-wait-online.service - Wait for Network to be Configured.
See 'systemctl status systemd-networkd-wait-onlie.service' for details

When I run the command suggested above, all I see is exited with status=1/FAILURE.
Digging around the internet I figure out I could check the networkctl. When I run the command networkctl list I get the following result:
IDX LINK  TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo    loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 end0  ether    off         unmanaged
  3 wlan0 wlan     off         unmanaged

then I run the command sudo networkctl up 2, the list changes to:
IDX LINK  TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo    loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 end0  ether    routable    unmanaged
  3 wlan0 wlan     off         unmanaged

This helps my router to "see" the RPi but it still I can't ssh to it. And the RPi does not have a connection to the internet (it is connected to the router through ethernet cable).
After 5 new flashes and 12 hours of trying to fix it myself, I decided to not try to fix anymore and ask question here. I am sorry for the long text. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

The fact that all interfaces are listed as unmanaged indicates that you don't have any (valid?) systemd-networkd configuration files (i.e., .network in /etc/systemd/network) for any of the interfaces. If you are using something else to manage/configure your network interfaces (e.g. NetworkManager), you should just disable the networkd services (which includes the wait-online one) with systemctl disable systemd-networkd. I have no idea what RPiOS uses OOTB though. (In some cases you might be using networkd "indirectly", like in some netplan cases.)

I think official Debian uses its own "interfaces" / "ifup" stuff for networking, so maybe RPiOS does as well. In that case you may want to take a look at this (and manuals et al. linked there). (The thing is the OMV admin portal seems to allow you to mess with networking from there, which means you may need to find out what "backend" OMV would try to mess with first...)

Look to your interface configuration in OMV. I assume you are using IPv4.
You need to define the DNS server, as well as the Domain server. For my home lab I use both my router plus Cloudflare's 1.1.1.1 in the DNS field separated by a comma. & in the 'IP addresses of domain name servers' I use my router's (gateway) IP address. Further if you intend to not use IPv6 then disable it in the interface configuration. If you leave it enabled but unconfigured OMV will hand on boot waiting for the configuration that never arrives. It will eventually time-out and boot, but it's slow.
